# UICollectionViewController with custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout - Scrolling bug

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

I am using the custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout code below to achieve self-resizing with Auto Layout and a fixed width. It works fine, but the scrolling does not work properly. If the content is ~0-60 pixels out of bounds, it simply does not allow scrolling. When it's a little higher, it scrolls but with a stutter and a sudden increase in the height of the scroll bar.

```
class CustomFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
 override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)?.copy() as? UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
    guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return attributes }
    attributes?.bounds.size.width = collectionView.bounds.width
    return attributes
 }

 override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    let allAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
    return allAttributes?.flatMap { attributes in
        switch attributes.representedElementCategory {
        case .cell: return layoutAttributesForItem(at: attributes.indexPath)
        default: return attributes
        }
    }
 }
}
```

What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: Are you testing on iOS 9 or 10? Is it reproducible on both?

Comment: It's reproducible on both, I've tested it.